# Is there a way to get wakelock on android through the JNI/NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-wake-lock

I'm tryin' to get a wakelock on my android phone, but I can't find any info on doing this in c/cpp  through the NDK/JNI.
I have been googlin so long I can't see straight.  All I see is Java Java Java, and I need some C.  A small bit of C will do me.  :)

Does anyone know where I'd find a small bit of C that achieves a wakelock on an android device?

Why I need it... I'm creating a lib to do a very specific task and I want to include wakelock as part of that lib.  To keep what needs to be together together and not mix my code where I don't have to.

Comment: I am not aware of a supported way through the NDK to acquire or release a `WakeLock`.

Comment: kewl.. why comment on your lack of knowledge?

Comment: On StackOverflow, many questions get asked and garner no answers. For questions like yours ("tell me how to do X"), the person asking the question is then left without knowing whether the lack of answers means there is no way to do X, or whether nobody who knows chimed in with an answer. In some of these cases, I will post a comment, indicating that I think the answer is "there is no way to do X", in case you do not get any actual answers, so you have a way of interpreting the silence. If I'm *positive* X cannot be done, I will post that as an answer.

Comment: Ah.  I more often then not don't believe the "there is no way".  There  is always a way.  It may mean breaking some rules, but given enough time "there is no way" melts away.  I found a way to turn on the sensors when the screen is off.  It means I have to rewrite the firmware.. but there is a way.  Surely there is a way to control basic linux power management.  Just how deep I dig is up to me.  There is always a way.

Comment: why not doing system("echo 'mylock' > /sys/power/wake_lock") ?

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple method is to do something like this

```
system("echo 'mylock' > /sys/power/wake_lock");
```

Comment: This requires root access.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do all the work in C, if you wish. But to acquire a wake lock correctly, you need at least the ApplicationContext. This means that your natvie code will still depend on Java level cooperation, like the NativeActivity.

You will simply use JNI to find the necessary classes and method id's.

Comment: do you mean my c has to call java functions?  That seems nonsensical. I mean it will adhere to implementation hiding if I put the calls to java in my lib, but Uggh.. that smells fishy to me.  There has to be a way.

Comment: did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done using JNI because dex engine handles wakelock control.  There is a bit of code posted that neglects all error checking and exception handling here: http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=50228
(shamelessly copy&pasted for google readers if the link ever breaks.)

```
// constructing the lock
 JNIEnv* jni = 0;
Context->App->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&jni, NULL);
if (jni)
{
    jclass classNativeActivity = jni->FindClass("android/app/NativeActivity");
    jclass classPowerManager = jni->FindClass("android/os/PowerManager");
    if (classPowerManager)
    {
        jmethodID idNativeActivity_getAppContext = jni->GetMethodID(classNativeActivity, "getApplicationContext", "()Landroid/content/Context;");

        jobject AppContext = jni->CallObjectMethod(Context->App->activity->clazz, idNativeActivity_getAppContext);
        if (AppContext)
        {
            jmethodID idNativeActivity_getSystemService = jni->GetMethodID(classNativeActivity, "getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
            jstring POWER_SERVICE = jni->NewStringUTF("power");
            jobject PowerManager = jni->CallObjectMethod(AppContext, idNativeActivity_getSystemService, POWER_SERVICE);
            if (PowerManager)
            {
                jmethodID idPowerManager_newWakeLock = jni->GetMethodID(classPowerManager, "newWakeLock", "(ILjava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/PowerManager$WakeLock;");
                int SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK = 0x0000000a;
                long int ON_AFTER_RELEASE = 0x20000000;
                jstring jWakeLockTag = jni->NewStringUTF("com.entity.Polygame.MY_BRIGHT_SCREEN_LOCK_LOL");

                WakeLock = jni->CallObjectMethod(PowerManager, idPowerManager_newWakeLock, SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | ON_AFTER_RELEASE, jWakeLockTag);
                debugLog("constructed wake lock");

                jni->DeleteLocalRef(jWakeLockTag);
            }

            jni->DeleteLocalRef(POWER_SERVICE);
        }

    }

    Context->App->activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread();
}


// acquire / release (the lock is in "released" state when first constructed)

JNIEnv* jni = 0;
Context->App->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&jni, NULL);
if (jni)
{
    jclass wakeLock = jni->FindClass("android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock");

    if (locked) to acquire the lock
    {
        jmethodID idWakeLock_acquire = jni->GetMethodID(wakeLock, "acquire", "()V");

        jni->CallVoidMethod(WakeLock, idWakeLock_acquire);

        debugLog("acquired wake lock");
    }
    else // release the lock
    {
        jmethodID idWakeLock_release = jni->GetMethodID(wakeLock, "release", "()V");

        jni->CallVoidMethod(WakeLock, idWakeLock_release);

        debugLog("released wake lock");
    }

    Context->App->activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread();
    Active = locked;
}
```